# Nearby Message API MessageLisenter is not triggerd

Tags: android, iot, android-things, google-nearby

I am working on IoT project with NXP i.MX7D . In this project I used Google Nearby API to publish data from companion app to the things app . I have followed this project [nearby-kotlin](https://github.com/rodrigosimoesrosa/nearby-api-pub-sub-kotlin) . I have followed almost exactly as this repo . but in my case both of my app is publishing is subscribing successfully . Here are my code for two activity first one is companion app's `MainActiviy.kt` and second one is for the activity running on the NXP i.MX7D

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


/**
 * The entry point to Google Play Services.
 */
private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null

/**
 * A [MessageListener] for processing messages from nearby devices.
 */
private var messageListener: MessageListener? = null



/**
 * One minutes.
 */
private val ttlInSeconds = 60 * 3
/**
 * Sets the time in seconds for a published message or a subscription to live. Set to three
 * minutes in this sample.
 */
private val publishSubscriptionStrategy = Strategy.Builder().setTtlSeconds(ttlInSeconds).build()


private val savedInstance = Calculate::class.java.simpleName

private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName

private val keyUUID: String = "UUID_KEY"

private lateinit var calculation: Calculate

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    calculation = savedInstanceState?.get(savedInstance) as Calculate? ?:
            Calculate.builder(getUUID(getSharedPreferences(applicationContext.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)),
                    "0", "0", Operator.OPERATOR_PLUS)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.calculate = calculation

    setOperatorDrawable(calculation.operator)


    messageListener = object : MessageListener() {
        override fun onFound(message: Message) {
            Calculate.fromMessage(message).toString()
            resultTv.text = calculation.result
        }

        override fun onLost(message: Message) {

        }
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected)
        subscriberForMessage()


    fab_plus.setOnClickListener {
        publishMessage()
        calculation.operator = "Plus"
        calculation.operandOne = operandOneET.text.toString()
        calculation.operandTwo = operandTwoET.text.toString()
        setOperatorDrawable(calculation.operator)
    }

    fab_minus.setOnClickListener {
        Log.i(TAG, "minus clicked")
        publishMessage()
        calculation.operator = "Minus"
        calculation.operandOne = operandOneET.text.toString()
        calculation.operandTwo = operandTwoET.text.toString()
        setOperatorDrawable(calculation.operator)
    }

    fab_multiply.setOnClickListener {
        publishMessage()
        calculation.operator = "Multiply"
        calculation.operandOne = operandOneET.text.toString()
        calculation.operandTwo = operandTwoET.text.toString()
        setOperatorDrawable(calculation.operator)
    }

    fab_divide.setOnClickListener {

        if (calculation.operandTwo.equals("0")) {
            Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Divide by zero exception", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        publishMessage()
        calculation.operator = "Divide"
        calculation.operandOne = operandOneET.text.toString()
        calculation.operandTwo = operandTwoET.text.toString()
        setOperatorDrawable(calculation.operator)
    }

    buildGoogleApiClient()
}


private fun setOperatorDrawable(operator: String?) {

    when (operator) {
        "Plus" -> operatorIV.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add)
        "Minus" -> operatorIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_minus_symbol)
        "Multiply" -> operatorIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_multiply)
        else -> operatorIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_divide)
    }
}


private fun getUUID(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): String {
    var uuid = sharedPreferences.getString(keyUUID, "")

    if (uuid.isEmpty()) {
        uuid.apply {
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(keyUUID, this).apply()
        }
    }

    return uuid
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    outState?.putSerializable(savedInstance, calculation)
}

private fun buildGoogleApiClient() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        return


    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this@MainActivity)
            .enableAutoManage(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
            .build()
}


/**
 * Publishes a message to nearby devices and updates the UI if the publication either fails or
 * TTLs.
 */
private fun publishMessage() {
    Log.i(TAG, "publishing msg")


    val option: PublishOptions = PublishOptions.Builder().setStrategy(publishSubscriptionStrategy)
            .setCallback(object : PublishCallback() {
                override fun onExpired() {
                    super.onExpired()

                    Log.i(TAG, "Message Publish expired")
                    runOnUiThread { Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Publish expired", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                }
            }).build()

    Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, calculation.toMessage(), option)
            .setResultCallback { status ->
                if (status.isSuccess) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "publishing was successful")
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "publishing successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Couldn't publish " + status, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

}

/**
 * Subscribes to messages from nearby devices and updates the UI if the subscription either
 * fails or TTLs.
 */
private fun subscriberForMessage() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscribing")

    val option: SubscribeOptions = SubscribeOptions.Builder().setStrategy(publishSubscriptionStrategy)
            .setCallback(object : SubscribeCallback() {
                override fun onExpired() {
                    super.onExpired()

                    Log.i(TAG, "Subscription expired")
                    runOnUiThread { Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Subscription expired", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                }
            }).build()

    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, messageListener, option)
            .setResultCallback { status ->
                if (status.isSuccess) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "subscription was successful")
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Subscription successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Couldn't subscribe " + status, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

}

/**
 * Stops publishing message to nearby devices.
 */
private fun unpublish() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Unpublishing.")
    Nearby.Messages.unpublish(mGoogleApiClient, calculation.toMessage())
}


override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected")
    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "GoogleApiClient connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    publishMessage()
    subscriberForMessage()
}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(i: Int) {
    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Google Api connection Suspended", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 }

override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "connection Failed" + connectionResult.errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 } }
```

activty for the app running on things

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


/**
 * The entry point to Google Play Services.
 */
private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null

/**
 * A [MessageListener] for processing messages from nearby devices.
 */
private var messageListener: MessageListener? = null


/**
 * One minutes.
 */
private val ttlInSeconds = 60 * 3
/**
 * Sets the time in seconds for a published message or a subscription to live. Set to three
 * minutes in this sample.
 */
private val publishSubscriptionStrategy = Strategy.Builder().setTtlSeconds(ttlInSeconds).build()


private val savedInstance = Calculation::class.java.simpleName

private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName

private val keyUUID: String = "UUID_KEY"

private lateinit var calculation: Calculation


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    calculation = savedInstanceState?.get(savedInstance) as Calculation? ?:
            Calculation.builder(getUUID(getSharedPreferences(applicationContext.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)),
                    "0", "0", Operator.OPERATOR_PLUS)

    setOperatorName(calculation.operator)



    messageListener = object : MessageListener() {
        override fun onFound(message: Message) {
            Calculation.fromMessage(message).toString()
            Log.i(TAG , "message found "+calculation.operandOne)
        }

        override fun onLost(message: Message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "message lost " + message)
        }
    }

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ _, isChecked ->
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected)
            if (isChecked)
                subscriberForMessage()
            else
                unsubscribe()
    })

    buildGoogleApiClient()

}


private fun setOperatorName(operator: String?) {

    when (operator) {
        "Plus" -> operatorTv.text = "plus"
        "Minus" -> operatorTv.text = "minus"
        "Multiply" -> operatorTv.text = "times"
        else -> operatorTv.text = "divided"
    }
}


private fun getUUID(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): String {
    var uuid = sharedPreferences.getString(keyUUID, "")

    if (uuid.isEmpty()) {
        uuid.apply {
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(keyUUID, this).apply()
        }
    }

    return uuid
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    outState?.putSerializable(savedInstance, calculation)
}


private fun buildGoogleApiClient() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        return


    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this@MainActivity)
            .enableAutoManage(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
            .build()


}

/**
 * Publishes a message to nearby devices and updates the UI if the publication either fails or
 * TTLs.
 */
private fun publishMessage() {
    Log.i(TAG, "publishing msg")


    val option: PublishOptions = PublishOptions.Builder().setStrategy(publishSubscriptionStrategy)
            .setCallback(object : PublishCallback() {
                override fun onExpired() {
                    super.onExpired()

                    Log.i(TAG, "Message Publish expired")
                    runOnUiThread { Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Publish expired", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                }
            }).build()

    Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, calculation.toMessage(), option)
            .setResultCallback { status ->
                if (status.isSuccess) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "publishing was successful")
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "publishing successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Couldn't publish " + status, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

}

/**
 * Subscribes to messages from nearby devices and updates the UI if the subscription either
 * fails or TTLs.
 */
private fun subscriberForMessage() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscribing")


    val option: SubscribeOptions = SubscribeOptions.Builder().setStrategy(publishSubscriptionStrategy)
            .setCallback(object : SubscribeCallback() {
                override fun onExpired() {
                    super.onExpired()

                    Log.i(TAG, "Subscription expired")
                    runOnUiThread {
                        Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Subscription expired", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        checkBox.isChecked = false
                    }
                }
            }).build()

    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, messageListener, option)
            .setResultCallback { status ->
                if (status.isSuccess) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "subscription was successful" + status.statusMessage)
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Subscription successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(resultTv, "Couldn't subscribe " + status, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

}

/**
 * Stops publishing message to nearby devices.
 */
private fun unpublish() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Unpublishing.")
    Nearby.Messages.unpublish(mGoogleApiClient, calculation.toMessage())
}

/**
 * Stops subscribing to messages from nearby devices.
 */
private fun unsubscribe() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Unsubscribing.")
    Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(mGoogleApiClient, messageListener)
}


override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected")

    if (checkBox.isChecked)
        subscriberForMessage()

    publishMessage()

    //Snackbar.make(operatorTv, "GoogleApiClient connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(i: Int) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended")
    //Snackbar.make(operatorTv, "Google Api connection Suspended", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onConnectionFailed(connectionResult: ConnectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed")
    checkBox.isChecked = false
    //Snackbar.make(operatorTv, "connection Failed" + connectionResult.errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} }
```

if you guys need to check the class which has been serialized and deserialized with Gson to send as payload nearmy message this calsses are [Calculate](https://github.com/1abid/AndroidThings-calculator-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vutkathings/increment/Calculate.kt) & [Calculation](https://github.com/1abid/AndroidThings-calculator-/blob/master/thingscalulator/src/main/java/com/vutkathings/calculation/Calculation.kt)

this is my Hello world type project for IoT . Help and suggestion is appreciated .

Thanks is advance

Comment: It seems like you never call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`. Can you add that call and see if you get the onConnected callback?

Comment: @NickFelker basically I followed this code from google code samles (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/blob/master/messages/NearbyDevices/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/samples/nearbydevices/MainActivity.java) 

there code is working . there was no  mGoogleApiClient.connect() in there code . where should I call this function

Answer (score 0):

The Google Nearby API is proving really tricky to work with. I am having the same problem with it, in my *JAVA* code, which was working perfectly until **today**. I created my ***NearbyManager*** Class to help automate and clear up the mainline code. Suddenly I'm not able to publish. **My publish Success Callback is never fired**. *Nor do I receive any messages*.

Look at your **Log**, I found out that somehow my **API Key was not accepted by Google** (I cleared my Log so no snap!), because my *SHA1(Android Debug Key)* fingerprint had changed (Again, makes no sense to me why, if anyone can explain, I'll be grateful), so I went to my **Console** and updated my fingerprint. This might have worked, though it's not been very long since I made that change, I'm yet to see results or test.

My code is not a solution to the problem, but is more of a prerequisite I put together to get people started with the *Nearby API*! We don't have a supporting class as such and I figured this would *help anyone starting out*! *This should help you to find missing pieces in your puzzle*! Good luck!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Message;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessageListener;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessagesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.PublishCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.PublishOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Strategy;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class NearbyManager {
    private boolean isSubscribing = false;
    private boolean isPublishing = false;
    private Activity current;
    private MessagesClient mMessageClient;
    private MessageListener mMessageListener;
    private static final Strategy PUB_STRATEGY = new Strategy.Builder()
            .setTtlSeconds(Strategy.TTL_SECONDS_DEFAULT).build();
    private static final Strategy SUB_STRATEGY = new Strategy.Builder()
            .setTtlSeconds(Strategy.TTL_SECONDS_MAX).build();
    private String mPubMessage;


    public boolean isSubscribing() {
        return isSubscribing;
    }

    public boolean isPublishing() {
        return isPublishing;
    }

    public NearbyManager(Activity activity){
        current = activity;
        PermissionManager.checkPerms(current);
        mMessageClient = Nearby.getMessagesClient(current);
        mMessageListener = new MessageListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFound(Message message) {
                if(message != null){
                    //DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onLost(Message message) {
                Toast.makeText(current, "Device is lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

    }
    public void publish(final String message){
        mPubMessage = message;
        PublishOptions options = new PublishOptions
                .Builder()
                .setStrategy(PUB_STRATEGY)
                .setCallback(new PublishCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onExpired() {
                        super.onExpired();
                        current.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                isPublishing = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                //.setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY) <-- removed this
                .build();
        mMessageClient.publish(new Message(message.getBytes()), options).addOnSuccessListener(current, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(current, "Publishing! Message:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        isPublishing = true;
    }
    public void subscribe(){
        SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(SUB_STRATEGY)
                .setCallback(new SubscribeCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onExpired() {
                        super.onExpired();
                        Toast.makeText(current, "No longer Subscribing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        current.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                isSubscribing = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                //.setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY) <-- removed this
                .build();
        mMessageClient.subscribe(mMessageListener, options).addOnSuccessListener(current, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(current, "Subscribing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        isSubscribing = true;
    }
    public void unsubscribe(){
        if(isSubscribing && mMessageClient != null)
            mMessageClient.unsubscribe(mMessageListener);
        isSubscribing = false;
    }
    public void unpublish(){
        if(isPublishing && mMessageClient != null)
            mMessageClient.unpublish(new Message(mPubMessage.getBytes()));
        isPublishing = false;
    }

}
```

One recommendation I would give is to trace your function calls by placing Log or Toast statements in your function call body. Like inside mMessageListener, publish and subscribe.

plus I didn't read much of your code, but I hope you are programatically checking if publish and subscribe is a success using onSuccessListeners.

Comment: Finally started working again. I tried a lot of things until removing `.setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)` made it work again.