# Nearby Messages using an IntentService

Tags: android, beacon, android-intentservice, google-nearby, android-ble

Initially I setup a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive intents from the [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview).

```
class BeaconMessageReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Nearby.getMessagesClient(context).handleIntent(intent, object : MessageListener() {
            override fun onFound(message: Message) {
                val id = IBeaconId.from(message)
                Timber.i("Found iBeacon=$id")
                sendNotification(context, "Found iBeacon=$id")
            }

            override fun onLost(message: Message) {
                val id = IBeaconId.from(message)
                Timber.i("Lost iBeacon=$id")
                sendNotification(context, "Lost iBeacon=$id")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun sendNotification(context: Context, text: String) {
        Timber.d("Send notification.")
        val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Notifications.CHANNEL_GENERAL)
                .setContentTitle("Beacons")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_white)
                .build()

        manager.notify(NotificationIdGenerator.nextID(), notification)
    }

}
```

Then registered this receiver in my `MainActivity` after location permissions have been granted.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ...

    private fun onLocationPermissionsGranted() {
        val filter = MessageFilter.Builder()
                .includeIBeaconIds(UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FEED"), null, null)
                .build()

        val options = SubscribeOptions.Builder().setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY).setFilter(filter).build()

        Nearby.getMessagesClient(context).subscribe(getPendingIntent(), options)
    }

    private fun getPendingIntent(): PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, Intent(context, BeaconMessageReceiver::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

}
```

This worked well while the app was open, but does not work when the app is closed. So I found [this example](https://medium.com/indianic/setting-up-beacons-and-messages-by-using-nearby-api-devoid-beacon-manager-app-e39da84e1f5e), that demonstrates how to setup an `IntentService` to receive messages while the app is in the background.

The example does use the [`Nearby.Messages`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/Messages) class, which was deprecated in favor of the [`MessagesClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/MessagesClient). So I replaced the deprecated code with the `MessagesClient` implementation.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ...

    private fun onLocationPermissionsGranted() {
        val filter = MessageFilter.Builder()
                .includeIBeaconIds(UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FEED"), null, null)
                .build()

        val options = SubscribeOptions.Builder().setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY).setFilter(filter).build()

        Nearby.getMessagesClient(context).subscribe(getPendingIntent(), options)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Timber.i("Subscribed successfully.")
                startService(Intent(this, BeaconMessageIntentService::class.java))
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Timber.e(exception, "Subscription failed.")
            }
    }

    private fun getPendingIntent(): PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, Intent(context, BeaconMessageIntentService::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

}
```

And this is the `IntentService` (which is almost identical to my `BroadcastReceiver`).

```
class BeaconMessageIntentService : IntentService("BeaconMessageIntentService") {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.let {
            Nearby.getMessagesClient(this)
                    .handleIntent(it, object : MessageListener() {
                        override fun onFound(message: Message) {
                            val id = IBeaconId.from(message)
                            Timber.i("Found iBeacon=$id")
                            sendNotification("Found iBeacon=$id")
                        }

                        override fun onLost(message: Message) {
                            val id = IBeaconId.from(message)
                            Timber.i("Lost iBeacon=$id")
                            sendNotification("Lost iBeacon=$id")
                        }
                    })
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(text: String) {
        Timber.d("Send notification.")
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Notifications.CHANNEL_GENERAL)
                .setContentTitle("Beacons")
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_white)
                .build()

        manager.notify(NotificationIdGenerator.nextID(), notification)
    }

}
```

`onHandleIntent` is called, and the `Intent` is not `null`; yet for some reason `onFound()` and `onLost()` are never called. Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a solution but what I found is this ([credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896331/4759619)):
I've tried a few configurations including a `BroadcastReceiver` and adding a `JobIntentService` to run the code in the background, but every time I got this the `onExpired` callback which you can set to the `SubscribeOptions`:

```
options.setCallback(new SubscribeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onExpired() {
        super.onExpired();
        Toast.makeText(context.get(), "No longer Subscribing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When the subscribe occurred in the background it was delayed, but it was still called.

Notes:
1. When I've tested with `Strategy.BLE_ONLY` I did not get the `onFound` callback.
2. From Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages):

> Background subscriptions consumes less power than foreground
>   subscriptions, but have higher latency and lower reliability

When testing I found this "*lower reliability*" to be an understatement: `onFound` was rarely called and I never got the `onLost`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but I had the same problem and found out by debugging that it is an issue related to this error: "Attempting to perform a high-power operation from a non-Activity Context". This can be solved when calling `Nearby.getMessagesClient(this)` by passing in an activity context instead of this.

In my case I added a class extending Application which helps in returning this context (the below is in java but should be translatable to kotlin easily)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Activity currentActivity = null;

    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
        return currentActivity;
    }
    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity){
        this.currentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }
}
```

And in my base activity, from which all activities extend, I set the current activity by calling `((MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext()).setCurrentActivity(this);` in the constructor.

My service can then call getMessagesClient with the correct context like below:

```
final Activity context = ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();
Nearby.getMessagesClient(context).[...]
```

Do not forget to register your Application class in the AndroidManifest:

```
<application
android:name="com.example.xxx.MyApplication"`
```